# Good alternative to Squirrel.Windows

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce, squirrel.windows

Recently I implemented [Squirrel.Windows](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) in one of my programs. It worked fine for basic functionality.

Problem is that main methods are all internal and we are left out to use Extension methods or do our own implementation. Plus, Squirrel project has too many open issues, so I think it wont be a nice project to work with.

Is there any library with similar functionalities, but at the same time gives me more control and let me use the already-implemented code?

Needs to be able to work with WPF.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a NuGet equivalent for deploying content to end users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209184/is-there-a-nuget-equivalent-for-deploying-content-to-end-users)

Comment: They suggest Squirrel, which is the think i want to find an alternative of.
Still does not matter much anymore. I just started to make my own.

Comment: They suggested plenty others on that question. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Appreciate the edit. Good effort. I was a bit upset when I wrote the question, so I didn't even think about grammar. And those alternatives are not transparent as Squirrel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late but [AutoUpdater.NET](https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET) is a good solution for this, it works well with both Winform and WPF